# How to control the area of background so it only makes a limited area has color other area don't?

Tags: html, css, background

i have a mail icon, png transparent file. The file has width=50px & height=50px, but only the central part got a mail picture. The central part has width=25px & height=25px see (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGRVp.png).

I want that when user hoover the mail the background of the central part turn to Orange. At this moment, when i mouse over the whole background got orange like this picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgnEX.png). This is not good.

Pls see http://jsfiddle.net/ZDY55/.

in html

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGRVp.png" alt="close" title="message" width="25px"       height="25px" class="{style.mailIcon}"  />
```

In Css

```
.mailIcon:hover {   
  background: 10px 25px orange;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
 }
```

So how to make the central part get orange color only, not all the picture?.

[image]
[image: Mail Icon]

Comment: For that don't change the background. Change the img src on hover.

Comment: on my pc it changed the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider making two different pictures, one normal and one with the background you want.
An other option would be a container div ( not a good idea for me but it's gonna work )

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDY55/9/)

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGRVp.png" alt="close" title="Close message" width="25px" height="25px" 
    background="orange"  />
</div>

#container{
    margin-top:8px;

}
#container:hover{
    width:25px;
    height:16px;
    background-color:orange;

}
#container img{
    margin-top:-8px;    

}
```

A third option, take all the white space over your image.
With the clipped image you could use that.

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/aLkrqSn.png" title="Hosted by imgur.com" />

img{
   margin-top:8px;    
    width:25px;
}
img:hover{
    background-color:orange;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDY55/18/

Comment: so 2 picture approach and  container approach, which one is better, simpler?

Comment: Two pictures approach is simpler and better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two choices:

1. Use an image with non-transparent background. Use a raster editor like Gimp to achieve this
2. Use multiple elements styled up to fake this appearance

I personally recommend the first option, because it is the natural solution, and it does not need superfluous elements in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mailIcon">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGRVp.png" alt="close" title="Close message" width="25px" height="25px" background="orange"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mailIcon:hover {   
  background-color:orange;
  display:inline-block;
}

.mailIcon img {
  margin:-12px 0 -7px;
}
```

You can add other necessary fine-tuning

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/okagOyO/5/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: it sill have some orange on the top & the botton. Can u chop off them?

Comment: Yes I know but you can easily fix that with some margins ... see the edited version.